# Android sqlite database wait until initial population of data is completed

Tags: android, sqlite, fts3

I'm following the 'Searchable Dictionary' of Android examples and pre-populating my FTS3 database with some data (1200 records). I want to display 3 'default' records on initial load of my activity but I need to wait until all the records have been inserted into FTS3. When I look at the logs I see

02-17 10:26:44.188: D/WorldClockWidgetActivity(1188):  # of default cities : 0

02-17 10:27:11.668: D/CitiesDatabase(1188): DONE loading words.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDatabase = db;
        mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
        loadDictionary();
    }

    /**
     * Starts a thread to load the database table with words
     */
    private void loadDictionary() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadWords();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
enter code here
```

I tried to change the above to an ASyncTask but the issue is that my main activity's list adapter cannot be accessed from "CitiesOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper" where the data is being loaded.

My question was how can I tell if my data has been loaded so I can load default values and display to the user?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Move `loadWords()` into `onCreate()` and get rid of the thread.

Step #2: Call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()` and your query from an `AsyncTask` started by your activity or fragment, setting your `ListAdapter` in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. So my main activity will populate the database? In all android tutorials, we do the initial setup of data inside the DatabaseHelper class.

Comment: @hurric: "So my main activity will populate the database" -- no. "In all android tutorials, we do the initial setup of data inside the DatabaseHelper class" -- my above instructions do not modify this. However, "in all android tutorials", a `DatabaseHelper` class does not appear out of the aether, created by elves. Instead, a programmer creates an instance of it and calls `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()`. In your case, I am guessing that an activity (or fragment) does this.

Comment: Thanks. I think I didn't understand how I should structure my classes. I will do the following: `MainListActivity` to display the classes. `DatabaseOpenHelper` and a `DAO` class. `DAO` class will have an instance of `DatabaseOpenHelper` and I open/close it after each use. On initial onCreate of my `MainListActivity` I will create an instance of DAO in which I populate my data from a raw text file. inside an ASyncAdapter Class. My MainListActivity will know when the DAO is finished loading the data and after that query for my default values and display to the user.